# Understanding while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a newbie in Python. I can understand what a for loop does, but can't really understand what a while loop does. I knew it does repeat something while the condition is true, easy to say, but it's really hard to use it as far as I think.

Say, an example here:

```
while 1:
   rate(100) #what does this rate(100) do?
   try:
      'something'
   except:
      'something else'
```

I just can't understand it. Help!

Comment: is that all the code you have? Or is there a rate function defined elsewhere in your code?

Comment: The function "rate()" is called inside of your loop and is not necessary to understand a while-loop. Is your question about how a while-loop works or about the function "rate()" or both?

Comment: Thanks, I think both, rate() is from time import clock i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code you have provided is equivalent to this:

```
while True:
    rate(100) #what does this rate(100) do?
    try:
        'something'
    except:
        'something else'
```

In Python many expressions can be tested for truth (that is evaluate to `True` or `False` when used in conditions and logical operations). For example non-empty sequences or non-zero numbers as you have evaluate to `True`. So this loop will run forever or until some code explicitly breaks out of it. This is because the loop condition is hard-coded to `True` so will never evaluate to `False` to exit the loop.

The basic behaviour of the `while` loop in python is well explained in the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming). Unless you have a more specific question I would suggest you start there. Other [Python flow control](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) constructs are also described there.

Answer (score 2):

`while 1` is a special case of `while` loop: It's a so-called "infinite loop".

Of course nothing is infinite. What the code is saying is: Run the contents of this loop until something inside causes it to exit. There's no explicit test in the loop, so the exit condition must be inside.

Either that, or the loop is meant to run for the entire duration of the program, and the program will run until killed by the operating system - or you flip the big red switch on your PC.

Answer (score 2):

You have actually defined an infinite loop. `while 1:` means to run the code-block below infinite times. You can only exit from it using a `break` statement.

The `rate(100)` calls the rate method, which must be defined somewhere. Then a try-catch block is executed. First 'something' code is run. If no errors occur, then the execution returns to the top of the loop. In case of an error, 'something else' is run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `while 1` is an infinite loop that will run forever. I'm guessing here a bit but `rate(N)` looks like the sort of function that would try to do something 100 times a second (or minute or other time period), in which case it's likely to be a simple "sleep for time period divided by rate".

For example, `rate(100)` would, in that case, be a sleep for 1/100<sup>th</sup> of a second (or other time unit).

Bottom line, it looks like a loop which continously tries something 100 times per time unit and, upon failure, do something else (the exception).

Without more context, you're probably not going to be able to get much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The `while 1:` construction is a infinite loop, ie it never ends.

Answer (score 0):

`while  1` is an infinite loop - it will run forever.

The `while` loop is a statement that allows code to be run on a given boolean value.

You can find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop), and I've included the example given in the article below - converted to python.

```
x = 0
while (x < 3):
   print "x = %d\n" % x
   x++
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this:  http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD316.2.html